# has_many :through when join table doesn't contain FK to both tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a structure that isn't really a `has_many :through` example, but I'd like it to behave like one:

```
# user.rb
belongs_to :blog
has_many :posts

# post.rb
belongs_to :user

# blog.rb
has_many :users
has_many :posts, :through => :users  # this obviously doesn't work becase
                                     # both FKs aren't in the blogs table
```

I want to get ALL posts for a blog in an array. I'm aware that I can do this with Ruby using `each` or getting fancy with `collect`, but I'd like to let SQL do the work.

Can someone explain how I can set up my models in a way that lets me call @blog.posts using SQL, and Ruby, and explain which way is "better"?

**Edit:**

I know in SQL I can write something like:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE posts.user_id IN (
  SELECT users.id FROM users WHERE users.blog_id = 7
)
```

which obviously shows two queries are needed. I don't *think* this is possible with a `join`, but I'm not totally sure. It's obvious that a subquery is needed, but how do I get rails to build that subquery with ARel instead of having to return and use Ruby to loop and collect and such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting this in your `Post` model

```
scope :for_blog, lambda{|blog|
  where("user_id IN (SELECT u.id FROM users u WHERE u.blog_id = ?)", blog.id)
}
```

This will allow you to call `Post.for_blog(@blog)`. The objects returned by SQL must be cast as `Post`s (that's why I'd put the scope in the `Post` model).

Then, in your `Blog` model, put

```
def posts
  Post.for_blog(self)
end
```

By defining the virtual attribute, you should now be able to access a blog's posts via `@blog.posts`.

Comment: will this work if I access other relationship ON post? Like I need to do post.versions (another table) and other stuff..

Comment: You should be able to do @blog.posts.first.versions, unless I'm mistaken.